# Check API version

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this code

```
if (sdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    boolean wCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS;

    if(wCharge) {
        charge.setSummary("Charging (WiFi)");
    }
}
```

Basically I want to check the way the phone is charging (usb, ac, wifi). The `BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS` was introduced in the 17 bees, and so if I do a check to see if the installed version corresponds to JB 4.2. Eclipse tells me `Field requires API level 17 (current min is 11): android.os.BatteryManager#BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS`

Do I have to raise the `minSdkVersion` or can I leave it? Sorry for the question that may seem silly.

Answer (score 1):

No. You should build your app with **highest** SDK your need for your code (in this case 17) and keep `minSdkVersion` as you have it now as it tells the platform what is the **lowest** supported version by your app. This [is mentioned in official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html):

> **android:minSdkVersion**
>
> An integer designating the minimum API Level
>   required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent
>   the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is
>   lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always
>   declare this attribute.

Comment: Ok, so I can leave everything as it is. Thank you.